# re.search() TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x, regex, subprocess

```
import subprocess
import re

interface = input(" interface : ")
new_mac = input("new MAC : ")

print("Changing " + interface + " to " + new_mac)

subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig"])

ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", "eth0",])
print(ifconfig_result)

mac_addr_searchresult = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
print(mac_addr_searchresult.group(0))
```

I want the output to be just the mac address but it keeps returning me
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: I think `ifconfig_result.decode("utf-8")` in `re.search` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As tripleee pointed in comment another simple fix for `Python 3.7+` would be to just to pass `text=True` parameter in [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```py
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", "eth0",], text=True)
```

According to [`Python3 doc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> By default, [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) will return the data as encoded bytes

Since the data is encoded bytes you need to convert it to string, for that you can use [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode) (by default the encoding is `utf-8` for [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode))

```py
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", "eth0",])
ifconfig_result = ifconfig_result.decode()
```

Or you can [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode) it while passing to [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.search)

```py
mac_addr_searchresult = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result.decode())
```

If you want the output directly as string you can use [`subprocess.getoutput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getoutput)

Comment: Actually the simplest fix by far in Python 3.7+ is to add `text=True` to the keyword arguments. (The same flag was called `universal_newlines=True` in 3.5+)